# How to display an MVIMG (google camera motion photo) in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, photo, motion

Google camera makes a so-called 'motion photo', that contains a short, audioless mp4 video clip from before/after taking the photo. This is appended to the JPEG file, its precise location is noted in EXIF tags.

Now I want to show this in my blog. Problem is, I haven't found a single JS gallery that would offer support for this functionality. Short of implementing one myself, is there maybe a solution to (optionally) show the video component of MVIMG files in a browser, upon user interaction (e.g. via click, like in google photos)?